# How to show discount form on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, discount

I want to show a discount form on the checkout page. I have added this below code on

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                <item name="link" xsi:type="string" translate="true">{{baseUrl}}</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Check Out</argument>
            <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Check Out</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Check Out</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">uiComponent</item>
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string" translate="true">steps</item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="popUpForm" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save Address</item>
                                                                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">action primary btn btn-custom action-save-address</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="cancel" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cancel</item>
                                                                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">action secondary btn btn-custom3 action-hide-popup</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!--Disable default coupon-->
                                            <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <!--Add new coupon to beforeMethod region-->
                                            <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <move element="logo" destination="header"/>
    <referenceContainer name="checkout.header.wrapper" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Discount form its not showing. I want to display the above shipping address.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!--Disable default coupon-->
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <!--Add new coupon to beforeMethod region-->
                                                    <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: I have added the code, Still, discount form not appearing. Please check the updated code.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: A discount form showing two times in payment page. Please refer to this screenshot. (https://prnt.sc/q0g4hs)

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove discount form below payment method.

Comment: Have you added "<!--Disable default coupon-->" section as above code mentioned ?

Comment: Yes, I have added. Please, Check my update code.

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'item': Duplicate key-sequence ['children'] in key identity-constraint 'itemName'.

Comment: I am getting this error.

Comment: This means in your previous code the "discount" section is hidden because after adding this code, its calling twice. You need to comment or remove my code and check if its "discount section" is hidden or not.